# Test Django models without running migration or syncdb

Tags: django, unit-testing, migration, django-1.7

**EDIT**: The issue described below was caused not by bad workflow but by an apparent bug when loading fixtures. One of my apps had the fixture `initial_data.json`. The testing framework loads the fixture before performing the necessary migrations. (FWIW, I'm using Django 1.7 + python3.4) This issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961217/django-unittests-fail-because-of-fixture-load-issue). (My workaround: rename the fixture to `data.json`.)

I'll leave the rest of the post intact in case this helps someone else in the future.

I'm trying to use Django's built-in tests to rapidly test my Django models during development. Unfortunately, when I try this, I get the error:

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "app_relation" does not exist`

The workflow I was imagining was

1. Define a few model fields (possibly across apps)
2. Test logic using Django tests
3. Fix logic errors, modify fields, and iterate this process.

This way, I can build my models incrementally without creating a large number of migrations. Migrations create headaches for me because I frequently add, remove, and rename fields or models as I'm validating my logic.

For example, my model has demographic fields, and I'm not sure whether I should keep an `male_under_18` field or split it up into `male_under_5`, `male_5_to_9`, `male_10_to_15`, and `male_16_to_18` granularity.

It sure would be nice to verify the decision using `tests.py` **before** making my migrations.

My understanding was that Django's `manage.py test myapp` created a database independent of the development database, and so doesn't require that my development database match the current schema defined by my models.

If the workflow above is impossible (or downright silly), I'm open to other ways to solving my problem.

Related question: [django unit tests without a db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917587/django-unit-tests-without-a-db/). (Doesn't work because I want to test the DB!)

Comment: I'm not sure that workflow is the best workflow, but it should work (Django does create an independent test database that can be different than your current, working one).

Have you thought about just rolling back your migrations (after you figure out they aren't needed) and deleting the non-needed ones? That might save you test-writing time...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It turns out that the problem wasn't the workflow... it was actually was related to loading an initial_data.json fixture during testing, which appears to be a bug in Django 1.7 with python 3.4. I'll update the post to reflect this and link to the question where I found the answer.